# js getUserMedia() how to remember permission from user

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am use webRTC for video call and I want to know if there is a way to remember permissions given by user. I need it to for `Firefox`. In my code there is a functionality that makes it possible for the user to change the camera during a video call, or if disconnects the camera during a call then the next available camera will be automatically selected. For show media device names I, am using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` , 
but this function returns empty names in Firefox, because I need to use this function every time like this

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}).then(stream => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(deviceInfo => {
        ...                           
    });
});
```

I can use this code every time, when I need names, but it causes inconvenience, when every time a modal is shown for permission to use media devices, because in my code I use this function many times `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` (devices can be added or deleted, and I need to check the device names again every time).
When Firefox requests access for media devices use we can select a checkbox `Remember this decision`  and then everything works well and that's what I need somehow to use in my code.
Everything works fine in `Chrome`.
I hope that I was able to correctly describe what I want, I will be very grateful if someone can help.

Comment: i dont think it is true case, acc to doc. You can get values any Time https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Comment: yes it is work well in `Chrome` but in `Firefox` I have to use it every time after this `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})`  what i don't want to do

Comment: hahaa.. so mozila dont follow their own doc :-D

Comment: browser info ??

Comment: and even a problem if this `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})` does not return the promise, then there is no way to get the names of media devices

Comment: `Mozilla Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) for Ubuntu`